Puppeteer - Symbol.dispose ??= Symbol('dispose');
I'm using Puppeteer v22.8.1 on Node v18.19.0 and having an error below:
/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/disposable.js:9
Symbol.dispose ??= Symbol('dispose');
               ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/EventEmitter.js:13:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)

I have similar issue here: Symbol.dispose ??= Symbol('dispose') error in render.com, and an answer is to upgrade to latest Node version. Do i need to update to latest Node version or v18.19.0 will suffice?

Node has been supporting the nullish coalescing assignment operator since v15.0.0.

Does this answer your question? Getting unexpected token error in vercel while deploying (runs fine in development)
